# 2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" in docker-compose up

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start the server through `docker-compose up`

I'm get an error:

*2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"*

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'slack_bot1'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '****'
    volumes:
      - /opt/slack_bot/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    volumes:
      - /opt/slack_bot/redis_data:/var/lib/redis
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /home/slack_bot
ADD requirements.txt /home/slack_bot/
RUN set -e; \
        apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
                gcc \
                libc-dev \
                linux-headers \
                mariadb-dev \
                python3-dev \
        ;
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /home/slack_bot/
EXPOSE 8001
CMD ["python", "manage.py",  "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8001"]
```

**docker ps** log

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                                                                                                                         NAMES
68b61ca0ce74        slack_bot_web                          "python manage.py ru…"   8 minutes ago       Up 32 seconds                   0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp                                                                                                                        slack_bot_web_1
c5f254a527b0        mysql:5.7                              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 34 seconds                   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                                                                                           slack_bot_db_1
4cbc1fa3765e        redis:alpine                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 33 seconds                   6379/tcp                                                                                                                                      slack_bot_redis_1
```

**Django settings** of database

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'slack_bot1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
```

Comment: Where do you configure the location of the database in your application code?

Comment: Updated code...

Comment: did you try to set `'HOST': 'db'` in the django settings or do you really want to go via unix sock?

Comment: @Stefano `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)"`

Comment: keeping HOST set to db, can you try the following: `docker-compose up -d db`, wait a minute and then exec `docker-compose up web`

Comment: @Stefano something needs to be changed in django settings?

Comment: I'm referring to my previous comment

Comment: @Stefano but in my django settings host! = db

Comment: @Stefano go to the chat maybe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your django settings, you leave database host as EMPTY, then the default value would be `localhost`. When use `localhost`, mysql client driver will connect mysql server with `unix socket` not `tcp`.

So, for your case you need to export `unix socket` in your mysql container to volume, then your django app container utilize this volume to share the `unix socket`.

Next is what you needed to do:

1. Manual new a folder which later as volume to share your unix socket file

   (IMPORTANT: you could not rely on docker-compose to new this folder, you will encountered permission error)

   ```
   mkdir -p /tmp/slack_bot/mysqld && chmod -R 777 /tmp/slack_bot/mysqld
   ```
2. In your `docker-compose.yaml`, add one more volume to `mysql` service:

   ```
   db:
       image: mysql:5.7
       environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'slack_bot1'
          MYSQL_USER: 'root'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '****'
       volumes:
         - /opt/slack_bot/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
         - /tmp/slack_bot/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld
   ```
3. In your `docker-compose.yaml`, add one more volume to `web` service:

   ```
   web:
       build: .
       command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
       ports:
         - "8001:8001"
       depends_on:
         - db
       volumes:
         - /tmp/slack_bot/mysqld:/run/mysqld
   ```

   **NOTE:** here you say you get the error `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` as next, I'm not sure if you paste the all log as most offen it could be `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, nertheless, if the error is `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` then you should modify above example volume to `- /tmp/slack_bot/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld`

   > 2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

With above, now your web service could share the unix socket in mysql container.

Additional, configure `HOST` as `db` I think also could be another solution, just `unix socket` is much faster compared to use `tcp`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect django and db docker containers which are in the same machine but aren't in the same docker-compose file by the following steps:

- Use `host.docker.internal` as host in settings.py instead of localhost as following:

  ```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbName',
        'USER': 'dbUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbUserPassword',
        'HOST': 'host.docker.internal',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
  ```

  }
- Expose the port in db compose-file

  ```
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  ```